# print contents of memory past the NULL character

Tags: c++, c

What do i need to to do to print the contents of a memory provided that it can have null characters in between.
suppose i have an address 0X123.i want to print some 100 characters before this address in the memory and there can be some NULL characters in between and i want to print those NULL characters too.

Comment: Which language? Please pick one.

Comment: Do you want the NULL characters to have any particularly special sentinal value (or for that matter any of the other non-text characters)? Could you please provide some more context. Is this going to be output in user readable form?

Comment: Yes it would be better to have the output in user readable format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unformatted output:

```
cout.write(address, count);
```

Or for C:

```
fwrite(address, 1, count, stdout);
```